# Transposing data in SQL with multiple and duplicate observations

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, group-by, string-aggregation

I have a dataset that I want to transpose from long to wide. I have:

```
 **ID         **Question**        Answer**
   1            Follow-up to         a
   1            Follow-up to         a
   1            Follow-up to         b
   1            Follow-up to         c
   2            Follow-up to         b
   2            Follow-up to         c
   4            Follow-up to         a
   4            Follow-up to         b
   4            Follow-up to         b
   6            Follow-up to         a
```

What I want is the dataset to look like this:

```
**ID         **Follow-up to**
  1              a,b,c
  2              b,c
  4              a,b
  6              a
```

I want the multiple responses for each ID to show up in the same row and I want the duplicate responses for each ID to be removed. I got this to work in SAS using the first. and last. feature, but I am not sure how to accomplish this in SQL. The dataset has hundreds of thousands of rows with dozens of variables just like the 'follow-up to' example above. Currently, I am using the json feature to transpose and pull out all the variables that I want in the wide format, but the transformation is only carrying over 1 answer for each ID, whereas I need all of them to carry over in the new format.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 0):

You want string aggregation, and `distinct`. In standard SQL, you would phrase this as:

```
select id, listagg(distinct answer) within group(order by answer) follow_up_to
from mytable
group by id
```

Different database products may use another function for string aggregation (SQL Server has `string_agg()`, MySQL has `group_concat()`, and so on) - but the logic is the same.

In Postgres:

```
select id, string_agg(distinct answer, ',' order by answer) follow_up_to
from mytable
group by id
```

Comment: This wont work in Oracle as distinct not allowed inside listagg.

Comment: It is a postgres SQL database.

Comment: Thank you GMB for the reply. I am getting the following error when I tried your suggested code: ERROR:  cannot use DISTINCT with WITHIN GROUP. Given that I am running postgres sql, do you have any advice? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle then above query wont work as distinct is not allowed inside listagg:

```
WITH CTE1 as 
(select distinct id, answer from TABLE1)
SELECT ID, LISTAGG(ANSWER, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ANSWER)
FROM CTE1 GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select id, string_agg(distinct answer, ',') as answers
from t
group by id;
```

Note that I would strongly recommend arrays rather than strings for the result column, but you seem to specify a string.  Also, the ordering of the values in the string is arbitrary.  You have no column in the data to specify the ordering.  If you did, you could add an `order by` to the aggregation function.